# Adding multiple conditions to "if"

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to add multiple conditions for the visibility of an image.

I've read that people achieve this with

if (something) || (something else) || (something more)
  //do something

But, when I put || between my statements i get "syntax error on token, invalid onlysynchronized"

Is there another solution to this problem?

The code in question:

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int clicks = pref.getInt("Total_Clicks", 0);

//add another SharedPreferences here

    if (clicks < 25) || //add another statement here {
        mImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        subbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (clicks > 25) {
        mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        subbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: you just have to do it all inside the same parenthesis

Comment: The correct syntax for `||` in an if statement is `if (condition1 || condition2)`. Note that there is one set of parentheses around the entire thing.

Comment: Don't forget your closing brackets `}`

Comment: Try `if (clicks < 25 && yourcode < yourcode){`.

Comment: "I've read that people achieve this with..." I loled. Please refer to any basic java programming book or tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

All conditions need to be inside the parentheses of your if statement.

```
if ( clicks < 25 || add another statement here ) {
    ...
}
```

You can nest parentheses if you need to.

```
if ( (clicks < 25) || (add another statement here) ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Don't I feel silly now... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

the 'if' statement requires the condition to be inside parenthesis. So try like this:

```
if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bill the Lizard is right, but I will add some more info. Say you have:

```
if((x > y) || (x + y) && (x >= 1)) {

// do stuff

}
```

As Bill said, you need to have your conditions in parentheses as you want to have them evaluate first. Second, you should also understand that there is an order of precedence for even logical operators. The order goes:

1. `!(not)`
2. `&&(and)`
3. `||(or)`

Hope this helps

Comment: You don't actually *have* to have the inner parentheses, but it certainly makes the code a lot clearer.

Comment: What do you mean? the inner parentheses are there. `if((x > y) || (x + y) && (x >= 1))`

Comment: Seeing as this question is asking about Java, the first and last expressions don't need parentheses, and the parentheses around `x + y` don't matter because it's going to be an error no matter what you do anyway, since integer values cannot be cast to booleans, and booleans cannot be added together.